# Configure from a file with a preset name

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

Log4j2 seeks for a configuration file in the CLASSPATH. I don't want my Java app to depend on a startup script that would set a custom CLASSPATH. And while some sources say that the default CLASSPATH includes the current directory, when I place a log4j2.xml in the current directory it is not picked up, and I get a "no log4j2 configuration file found" message.

So I want to configure Log4j2 from a file with a preset name and location. (Or just give it a preset location, so it would test for log4j2-test.xml and then log4j2.xml - this would be even better).

Sounds simple, and in log4j 1 it was indeed simple. But somehow I can't find anything like this in Log4j2 documentation, which focuses on complicated use cases like custom configuration factories.

I would appreciate advice on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  specify the full path of the configuration file with this system property:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml
```

See also the [FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location).

Comment: I have now tried both `System.setProperty("log4j.configurationfile", "./log4j2.xml");` and `System.setProperty("log4j.configurationfile", "C:\\full\\path\\log4j2.xml");` but I still get the message about not being able to find the configuration file. When I added `System.setProperty("org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level","TRACE");` I did get the trace log on the console, so the setProperty mechanism works. The trace log does not show any attempt to open that file.

Comment: You misspelled the property. Use a capital F (camel case).